# Is the 2KD engine manual gearbox compatible with a 1KD?

Tags: engine, toyota, replacements, gear-ratio

The car is a Hilux Vigo 4WD , manual transmission.

Can I use a manual 5-gear gearbox that is designed for a 2.4L (2KD) engine with a 1KD 3.0L engine?

A duplicate post of this question : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/19658/10902

Comment: @SolarMike That link goes to a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellhousing and everything else perfectly fits, and the drive is smooth. what I am not sure is the nitty gritty like the size of the clutch.

Comment: You can [edit](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/52163/edit) to add further information to the question. Don't post this as a new answer. Please see [I posted something; why was it deleted?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1748/675)

Comment: I didnt fix the gearbox when i asked the question, now the gearbox is on the car and perfectly fits, isn't this what am supposed to say? @zaid